# Which cache does preloaded resources go to in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser-cache, preload

In this article https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf you can read that:

> Chrome has four caches: the HTTP cache, memory cache, Service Worker cache & Push cache. Both preload and prefetched resources are stored in the HTTP cache.

But in the article (about caches) the above article links to (https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/a-tale-of-four-caches/) you can read that:

> Explicit preload directives (`<link rel=preload>`) is another big case where the preloaded resources are stored in the Memory Cache.

So where does preloaded resources go to?

Answer (score 0):

It may go to both caches.

> When a resource is preloaded or prefetched is travels up from the net stack through to the HTTP cache and into the renderer’s memory cache. If the resource can be cached (e.g there’s a valid cache-control with valid max-age), it is stored in the HTTP cache and is available for current and future sessions. If the resource is not cacheable, it does not get stored in the HTTP cache. Instead, it goes up to the memory cache and stays there until it gets used.